# Php mysql get the nearest-latest record if a record is not exist (datetime based)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, select

Trying to get my head around, If I select a record such as `WHERE item_id='$item_id' AND date(datetime)='2012-06-25'` and if that record does not exist so I want to get the nearest-latest record after that date. How can I achieve that in a query?

<s>All I can think of the only way right now is if num_of_rows is 0 then I add 3 days period ahead to that day and search again and get the `DESC datetime LIMIT 1` (in case there are multiple rows). But who knows I can do it with just a query.</s>

The record could have multiple rows in one day. So if a particular date has no record, how to get the next nearest available data given the same $item_id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
 FROM table
 WHERE field <= '2012-06-25'
 ORDER BY field DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution. I think you're overcomplicating things, @Ardeus.

Comment: Yeah, seems simple enough. +1 from me.

Comment: I guess you are right, that should achieve the same result. I was thinking too much that since the data is all historical and there are alot of records involved that might affect the performance of query like when SORTING data from last year. That's why I thought if a record is not exist on that particular date, usually the next or next 2 days will have a new record of item_id that I want to search. The query actually is using two condition WHERE item_id and date. I guess I will accept your answer for now.

Comment: You could always add an index to the date column to speed things up.  Moreover, you could add `AND field >= '2012-06-20'` (five days earlier), or some other timespan in which you believe there would be at least one record.

Comment: If there are several record in one day, user still want to display those records (requirement changed -.-;). Let say 2012-06-25 has no record and go to the next DESC order, I cant just LIMIT it to 1 anymore nor I can remove the limit because it will include all remaining date. I will edit the paragraph 2 of my question.

Comment: just use the first query to find the date and fire a second query with the exact date to get the data.

Comment: @Andreas I indeed use two type of querying, find the latest date, if cannot find any record then I simple add few more days and check in recursive function. If you dont mind, is there any other way to get the latest date without DESC order? I have like hundred thousand records and sorting is really slowing the query down. May be using max() , what do you think?

Comment: Add an index on the date column.  Pretty sure Max() will run into the same problem if there is no index.

Answer (score 0):

This will bring back the item closest to the date that you enter into the query. It won't however look for before or after, just find the closest date to what you enter in.

```
select 
     min(abs(DATEDIFF(date(datetime),'2012-06-25'))) as minDiff
    ,yourID
from table1 
group by yourID 
order by 1 asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2012-06-25 00:00:00' AND 
                       DATE_ADD('2012-06-25 00:00:00', INTERVAL 3 DAY)
ORDER BY datetime ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

also create index on field datetime for faster performance.